# How to verify the username and password of Twitter in Window form Application c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, twitter

I have a requirement to check programmatically whether the UserName/Password for the Twitter account are valid or not.

**Code**

### **[I am following this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211128/twitter-verifying-username-and-password-in-c-sharp)**

```
public bool CheckTwitterCredentials(string UserName, string Password)
{
    // Assume failure
    bool Result = false;

    // A try except block to handle any exceptions
    try {
        // Encode the user name with password
        string UserPass = Convert.ToBase64String(
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(UserName + ":" + Password));

        // Create our HTTP web request object
        HttpWebRequest Request = 
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.xml");

        // Set up our request flags and submit type
        Request.Method = "GET";
        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Add the authorization header with the encoded user name and password
        Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + UserPass);

        // Use an HttpWebResponse object to handle the response from Twitter
        HttpWebResponse WebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();

        // Success if we get an OK response
        Result = WebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + Ex.Message);
    }

    // Return success/failure
    return Result;
}
```

I created a new account,My Email is verified. I can login now with my username and password. When i am trying to use the above code. I am getting UnAuthorized exception.

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used OAuth.

As far as I am aware, Twitter only accepts requests which have been OAuth'd.

See: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/verify_credentials

According to this, you need to be authenticated in order to verify credentials.

I don't see anywhere in your code where you have authenticated using OAuth, so unless it is hidden away somewhere I wouldn't expect your code to work.

In reality, Twitter is a pain of an API, and is likely to change over time (the 1.0 to 1.1 jump was a complete rewrite).

As a result, I would recommend using a library and letting them worry about that. I use TweetSharp. Sadly the main developer has left the project but it still works.

Comment: Can you tell how can u get _consumerKey, _consumerSecret, _accessToken and _accessTokenSecret in Window Forms Application ?

Comment: You get it at dev.twitter.com by creating an application. Seriously the documentation is good, why not give yourself an hour or two to read it thoroughly. https://dev.twitter.com/apps

Comment: You know, In order to crete app, it is necessary to provide the website and I don;t have any

Comment: It says "(If you don't have a URL yet, just put a placeholder here but remember to change it later.)"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Twitter API was updated. And code that you have provided is no more valid.

Comment: First of all, try to use different API url: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json